# Restrict ability to edit pages by username

Tags: plugins

I'm looking for a plugin or snippet with the following function:

There is a WordPress Website with approx. 30 registered users. Every user get 2 Pages to edit his or her Products. Everyone can view the content but only the registered user can edit his oder her own Pages.

Example:

Peter can edit Page Id 222, Page 223
Tom can edit Page Id 224, 225
Admin can edit all
All Pages will be shown to all unregistered Users

Is there a PlugIn which allow this setting? The most Member Plugins I have seen, only allow to set roles and hide or view the content for other users.

Thank you for your help!

Cheers Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I striked for something a bit more complex, but similar in the core. The rather old-ish [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/) can do that, or you try the Premium version of its successor [Press Permit](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/press-permit-core/). I befind both a bit complex if you only need a single usage option (manage page restrictions), but they work ;). Hope this helps!

Comment: Press Permit is great! Thanks physalis for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help ;).